# Why won't my glossary print, using glossaries pkg?

Tags: glossaries

I used `\makeglossaries` in the preamble.  Defined my terms, and issued `\printglossaries`.  I've been reading the manual but can't see what I'm missing:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\newglossaryentry{flux}{name=Flux,
description={(1) The rate of flow of metabolites through a metabolic pathway.  (2) The rate of transport per unit of area.}}

\glsaddall

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Edit: it is true I don't actually use the glossary terms in the text body - this is purely a stand-alone glossary.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An actual answer this time:

Use `makeglossaries <bare filename>` and then recompile the document, and all should be well.

My understanding is that you must compile the document *first*, since this is what generates the files `makeglossaries` acts on.

Comment: Is this supposed to be performed on the .tex file which includes your glossary, or on the .glo file itself?  Do I include this in the preamble, or is this to happen inside windows commandline terminal?  Thanks.

Comment: When `glossaries` was installed, you should have gained a command (a Perl script, specifically) called `makeglossaries`. Say your file is called `glossary.tex`. You would `cd` to the directory where it is and run `makeglossaries glossary`. Then it'll handle the rest and you can recompile your document. See my edit above.

Comment: Is this a one-time requirement or do I have to makeglossaries everytime I add new terms to the glossary?  The way it's set up seems a bit inconvenient, I'd rather not have to go thru this process in terminal everytime... :|

Comment: You could always write a script to automate the process.  As far as I can tell from the docs, this is the way it has to be done.

For instance, if you keep all your glossary files in one directory, you can make a simple batch file to `cd` to that directory and run `makeglossaries` on the file you want (or on all of them).

Comment: I wonder if there are alternative glossary packages which are handled entirely within the latex editor environment without the need to visit the terminal...?

Comment: Other then the deprecated `glossary` package, I can't think of any. The [LaTeX Wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Glossary) section on glossaries may be informative, though. Unfortunately, there doesn't appear to be a way around using the command line a little unless you're willing to do a little bit of scripting now. Alternatively, you need not recompile your glossary every time you add a new entry. Just do so periodically to check for errors. When you're ready to finish the glossary, run `makeglossaries` and you're done. That saves you the trouble of using the command line often.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, and for following through Jack.  You have helped tremendously.  :)

Comment: No problem at all. I hope it works out well for you. :)

Answer (score 2):

Have you used `makeglossaries`, `xindy` or `makeindex`, yet? [This section](http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#x1-3300010) suggests that you need to use one of them before the entries will print.

CW'd since it's really more of a comment than an answer.

EDIT: I've just tried that, and that's the way. Just run `makeglossaries <name of file>` and it'll work. Don't use any extension, though. Just the bare name of your file. Note non-CW answer now active.